# Suppressing Visio.Application alerts

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript that opens a Visio file in the background by using `Visio.Application` in invisible mode.

```
Set Visioapp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
Visioapp.Visible = False
Set Visio = Visioapp.Documents.Open(VisioFile)
```

This works fine except when I try to open a file that generates a pop-up while I'm processing it. If that happens, the application would show an alert to notify the user but since the application is invisible to the user (or running without a user present), the script just hangs indefinitely, waiting for input that won't be coming.

If I were writing VBA code for Excel or Word I could use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` (and/or possibly `DisplayEvents`). But in my VBScript the Visio application doesn't have that property. `Visioapp.DisplayAlerts = False` will give me the error "*Object doesn't support this property or method*".

**How do I suppress the popups generated by a Visio application opened from VBScript?**

Comment: If Visio has `Application.DisplayAlerts` and you have set `Visioapp` to be an instance of the Visio Application object (which is what you did) then you can try `Visioapp.DisplayAlerts = False` and it should work...

Comment: @Dave I agree, but that gives me an error (clarified the question). By that extension, could the problem be that the Visio application doesn't actually have that property?

Comment: There is no reason that VBS can't do something that VBA can do with Objects. Programming languages automatically generate late bound objects VBS uses (based on IDispatch)from the early bind VBA objects (although VBA can access it via Early or late binding). They both end up running the code in the VBA object as the VBS object just forwards the call on.

Comment: @Lilienthal Apparently Visio does have it, they just call it something different to the other Office apps... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767782.aspx

Comment: @Dave Good find. I actually stumbled on that page but ignored it thinking it covered something else. I just confirmed that the code works fine with `Excel.Application` so that seems to be the issue. Should I adjust the question to be Visio-specific?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221235(v=vs.85).aspx and click application and document to see what standard properties and methods programs have to implement.

Comment: You did set it to 1 not false. Read the docs.

Comment: @Noodles `DisplayAlerts` takes a boolean `AlertResponse` that Dave linked takes a number. I've confirmed that it works with that property.

Comment: That's why I was reminding him to set it to 1.

Comment: Fair. @Dave Thanks again for your assistance. Let me know if you want to submit `AlertResponse` as an answer or if I should self-answer it to mark this resolved.

Comment: @Noodles let's just be clear COM is not *"VBA objects"* it's just a mechanism used by both, the difference with VBScript is it only supports late-binding COM objects. There is no *"forward"*-ing on the call, they are both separate. While they share the similarities they are different and shouldn't be grouped together it just creates greater confusion.

Comment: *Although OLE Automation allows you to implement an IDispatch interface, a VTBL interface, or a dual interface (which encompasses both), Microsoft strongly recommends that you implement dual interfaces for all exposed OLE Automation objects. Dual interfaces have significant advantages over IDispatch-only or VTBL-only interfaces:* From Dual-Interface Support for OLE Automation Servers - Microsoft. c2001

Comment: @Lankymart *Interfaces Should Be Marked Dual
Dual interfaces are interfaces that support both IDispatch (also known as "late") as well as v-table binding. This means that when they are used inside strongly typed languages the calls are faster (because they are straight v-table calls). Dual interfaces should be used in all cases unless there is good reason not to. Dual interfaces are just as callable from scripting engines as standard IDispatch interfaces ...* Building COM Components That Take Full Advantage of Visual Basic and Scripting Ivo Salmre
Microsoft Corporation February 24, 1998

Comment: @Noodles What was the point in all that? I never called into question how late-binding / early-binding works?? You quoted all that and it was pointless.

Comment: *There is no "forward"-ing on the call, they are both separate. While they share the similarities they are different* just isn't true.

Comment: @Noodles I was talking about COM! The interfaces are COM and they **should** be duel to allow the same behaviour in both VB (late / early) and VBScript (late) bindings. I was talking about VB not forwarding the call, as you suggested in your first  comment - *"They both end up running the code in the VBA object"*, that statement is just wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summarizing the comments from [@Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958994/suppress-application-alerts-or-errors-in-stand-alone-vbs#comment67197987_39958994) and [@Noodles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958994/suppress-application-alerts-or-errors-in-stand-alone-vbs#comment67198190_39958994), the Visio [`Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766485.aspx) object does not have a property `DisplayAlerts` like other Office applications have. Instead it provides a property [`AlertResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767782.aspx) that allows you to define whether the application should respond to alerts with *OK*, *Cancel*, *Abort*, *Retry*, …

To have the application respond with *OK* to all alerts change your code to something like this:

```
Set Visioapp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
visioapp.AlertResponse = vbOk
Set Visio    = Visioapp.Documents.Open(VisioFile)
```

Note that in this case you can use the [symbolic constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1ft6yf3.aspx) that VBScript already provides (`vbOk`, `vbCancel`, `vbAbort`, `vbRetry`, …). For application-specific constants (e.g. the `SaveFlags` for the [`SaveAsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768149.aspx) method) this won't work, though. In those cases you'll have to either use the numeric value:

```
Visio.SaveAsEx "C:\path\to\output.vsd", 1
```

or define the constant in your script:

```
Const visSaveAsRO = 1
...
Visio.SaveAsEx "C:\path\to\output.vsd", visSaveAsRO
```

Comment: I have no issue with you answering in fact it's admirable that you set it to a community wiki, but surely you should at least leave it and give others who initially commented time to leave an answer first?

Comment: Nobody seemed to be willing to post their answers as an answer, so I summarized the comments in a wiki answer, lest the question remain without an actual answer.

Comment: I know but @Dave hasn't be active in the last 1 hour so they have likely not seen this, I think you have to give people more then a hour to respond.

Comment: There are already too many questions with comments that should have been answers. He could have posted an answer instead of the comment where he linked to the documentation. Besides, nobody's stopping him from posting an answer of his own anyway.

Comment: Fair enough. It was a throw away comment.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't really mind and I definitely appreciate the additional info on using symbolic constants in this scenario but it does discourage Dave from submitting his own answer. Neither you nor I care for the rep but perhaps Dave does. It's why I didn't immediately self-answer after confirming the solution based on Dave's link.

Comment: I appreciate the concern @Lankymart - but I didn't have the time to do more than try to point in the direction of the answer for the asker, and I'm not that worried about the rep either.  Key thing is that the question got answered and we have a clear, concise and helpful explanation.