# Close an object without saving changes

Tags: vbscript, visio

I have the below `For` loop. As you can see, I am trying to close the specific file if it is open.

The below set-up asks me whether I want to save the file. How do I close it without saving the file?

I've tried setting `DisplayAlerts` to `False` as well as `ObjDoc.close False`

The error I am getting is 'Property Let procedure not defined and Property Get procedure did not return an object'

```
Sub MacroExample()
' Define local variables
Dim objVisio
Dim objDoc
 Dim blnVisioCreated

' Initialize Vision application reference variable
Set objVisio = Nothing

' Assume Visio is already running, then try and get a reference to it
blnVisioCreated = False
On Error Resume Next
Set objVisio = GetObject(, "Visio.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

' If Visio was not running already load it and remember that we created it
If objVisio Is Nothing Then
   Set objVisio = CreateObject("Visio.InvisibleApp")
   blnVisioCreated = True
End If

' See if out drawing is already open, if so close it
For Each objDoc In objVisio.Documents
  If objDoc.Name = "Drawing1.vsd" Then
     'objVisio.DisplayAlerts = False
      objDoc.alertrespons = 0
     objDoc.Close False
     Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Best to show the exact code you're using when you see the error you describe, and indicate which line triggers it.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767415.aspx): "You can use the AlertResponse property to prevent the alert from appearing."

Comment: @Comintern The alertresponse gives me 'object doesn't support' error. In addition, as per documentation, it doesn't have a integer to suppress the alerts? (display alert has zero)

Comment: @TimWilliams I've updated the code prior to this up to this point; this is in a vbs file

Comment: You have a typo in your code `alertrespons` and it's a property of the Application, not the Document

Comment: Questions have their first few lines displayed in some views on this site - by putting the code first your question's summary looks like gibberish. I've edited to swap the code and its description, and also pretty sure "Pretty let" was meant to be "Property Let" ;-)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39958994/1630171).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all!

I've used this line before the closing line

```
objVisio.AlertResponse = vbNo
objDoc.Close
```